# ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to develop a Flutter app and run it from Chrome instance. This app uses firebase emulator for the development purpose but somehow when I make changes to any code and when Flutter tries to reload the app, it paused the debug session and point me to the error.

[image: an image of a debugger pointing to the error]

However, it doesn't show any details about the error in the debug console other than this

```
Restarted application in 774ms.
[GETX] Instance "LoggerService" has been created
[GETX] Instance "LoggerService" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "AuthService" has been created
[GETX] Instance "AuthService" has been initialized
[2022-04-14T16:06:38.386Z]  @firebase/firestore:
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator': InternalError: No frame with index 46.
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'async': InternalError: No frame with index 46.
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator': InternalError: No frame with index 46.
```

I tried several things including:

1. Restarting the emulator suite using `0.0.0.0` and set the app to point out to said host
2. Changing `10.0.2.2` to my computer's IP address (`192.168.x.x`)
3. Using `localhost` instead of `10.0.2.2` as pointed on the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/start)

But this still happening everytime I hit `ctrl + S`.

I did not modify anything in the emulator script, it was a fresh install. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my `AuthService` implementation is causing this issue, it works when I commented the event listener.

`auth_service.dart`

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:prisma_inventa/app/routes/app_pages.dart';

class AuthService extends GetxService {
  static AuthService get instance => Get.find();

  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final user = Rx<User?>(null);
  bool get authenticated => user() != null;

  Future<AuthService> init() async {
    user.bindStream(_firebaseAuth.authStateChanges());
    ever(user, _redirectIfUnauthenticated);
    return this;
  }

  void _redirectIfUnauthenticated(User? user) {
    // print('AUTH STATE CHANGED, user: ${user.toString()}');
    // if (user == null) {
    //   Get.offAllNamed(Routes.AUTH);
    //   return;
    // }

    // Get.offAndToNamed(Routes.HOME);
  }

  ...
}
```